# How is called this type of implementation? RecyclerView, Layout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview, layout

Hello I am using recyclerView, I've just watched in a tutorial that they use this

Inside a recyclerView override functions
when this is called

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false  )
    //esto lo unimo al marco estandar de noticias
    return ViewHolder(v)

}
```

And bring `R.layout.rowlayout`

and in this layout is the following code

[image]

The thing is that in the header, it does not call
`androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` or `LinearLayout`
instead of that call this code `app:com.example.perri.rowlayout` that will bring the Kotlin file

[image]

I'd like to know how this kind of approach called, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of classes are [Custom View Components](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components)

Android offers a number of predefined layouts and widgets, such as `LinearLayout`, `ConstainLayout`, `Button`, etc.
If these components don't meet your needs, you can create your own to change their appearance or behavior.

There are several approaches, in your example you are [Modifying an Existing View Type](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components#modifying), to create a custom `ConstraintLayout`, and use it as the row layout of the `recyclerView`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've another question. I want to comunicate this custom view with a fragment, with a listener, but because this class does not extend fragment, I could not. Do you know any source or information to try to achieve this task?